# Unauthorized Payment Paypal error 401 LIVE MODE

Tags: java, android, ios, web, paypal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqXEc.png)I am trying to get the API to work in "Live" mode, I have had no issues with integrating the SDK through Sandbox, but once I switch to live I get:
Unauthorized Payment Paypal error 401 LIVE MODE
also in my account product i have this:

[image]

Comment: Which API are you using?

Comment: "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment"   this one

Comment: i used paypal api ;   i get the metadataid and  the refresh token but in the  final step "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment" give me  Unauthorized Payment

Comment: Can you paste the entire response when you get the token - there will be something called scopes that help identify which apis you can call - you cal blank kit the token from the response before pasting

Comment: D/mainresult: {"scope":"https://uri.paypal.com/services/reporting/search/read https://uri.paypal.com/services/subscriptions https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card https://uri.paypal.com/services/applications/webhooks https://uri.paypal.com/services/payments/futurepayments openid https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.*",

Comment: This looks good does it fail on Create payment or execute payment ?

Comment: on execute payment

Comment: That's totally weird can you paste the request response including headers for both the create and execute ?

Comment: have you find any solution in this. today i try to perform same thing and get the same error. Is there is something to do with future payment and payout permission.Because i store paypal card token and then making payment

Comment: try to use braintree  https://www.braintreepayments.com/features/paypal